# What is -u from cURL when adding an authorization header to an http request

Tags: api, curl, mixpanel

I am trying to test one of Mix Panel's API endpoints. I'm using Postman to do this, and in Mix Panel's documentation they use cURL to show you how to make the request. When entering the URL, and the POST data for the request, it works in the sense that it hits the right place, and tells me that I need to be authenticated by adding an authorization header. What I'm confused on is, what should the key be for the header ? in their cURL example its -u API_SECRET, so would the authorization header key be 'username' ?

From documentation

```
# this uses a test project API secret, replace ce08d087255d5ceec741819a57174ce5
# with your own API secret
curl https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql \
    -u ce08d087255d5ceec741819a57174ce5: \
    --data-urlencode params='{"from_date":"2016-01-01", "to_date": "2016-01-07"}' \
    --data-urlencode script='function main(){ return Events(params).groupBy(["name"], mixpanel.reducer.count()) }'
```

If I wanted to create an AJAX query for example

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql',
        data: {
            'params': '{"from_date":"2016-01-01", "to_date": "2016-01-07"}',
            'script': '\'function main(){ return Events(params).groupBy(["name"], mixpanel.reducer.count()) }\''
        },
        headers: {
            <WHAT GOES HERE>: API_SECRET
        }
        }).then(function success(response){
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            console.log(response)
        }, function error(response){
            console.log('There was an error running JQL');
            console.log(response.error)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, your `API_SECRET` is the username and there is no password. So using `curl -u <API_SECRET>:` without any "username" key is correct.

From the mixpanel documentation on an example call https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/data-export-api

> Authorization steps The Data Export API accepts Basic access
>   authentication over HTTPS as an authorization method. To make an
>   authorized request, put your project's API Secret in the "username"
>   field of the Basic access authentication header. Make sure you use
>   HTTPS and not HTTP - our API rejects requests made over HTTP, since
>   this sends your API Secret over the internet in plain text.
>
> Examples Here's an example of a properly-authenticated request made
>   with cURL:
>
> curl https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/segmentation/ \
>       -u YOUR_API_SECRET: \
>       -d from_date="2016-02-11" -d to_date="2016-02-11" -d event="Viewed Page"

Comment: If I'm not using cURL, and need to add an authorization header, would it just be 'username': API_SECRET. I tried that, but I still get an authentication issue.

Comment: No, the `-u` indicates that basic HTTP auth should be used. The header would be `'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('<YOUR_API_SECRET>:')`. But I'd encourage you to look at the mixpanel javascript API https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript if you haven't already.